# Storing enum values from another namespace in an array

Tags: c++

I would like to store the values from an enum variable in another namespace in an array.

So assuming the enum is declared as follows

```
namespace something
{
    enum IWANT
    {
        FOO = 0,
        BAR,
        BLARGH,
        MEH,
        SIZE
    };
} // namespace SOMETHING
```

and I can access this enum else were using

```
something::FOO
```

Is it possible to store certain variables I want from something in an array? For example

```
<varType> onlyWhatIwant[3] = {something::FOO, something::BAR, something::SIZE}
```

Such that when the variable is used as follows `onlyWhatIwant[1] points to the something::BAR`

I don't know if this is even possible or not but thought I would ask before looking for another route.

Comment: Of course it is, try it out. I don't really understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums are basically a way to define integer constants; they don't have some address associated so that you can have a pointer to them in the traditional sense. What you want to do is possible to some extent (check my full example below); however, the array elements will not point to something else. They will just have the value equal to the assigned constant (foo::first and foo::second, in my example).

```
namespace foo {
    enum X {first, second};
};

int main() {
    foo::X t[3] = {foo::first, foo::first, foo::second};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I found out what the issue was...I initialized the variable in the wrong location! Thank you for the example!

Answer (score 0):

for an enum like this

```
namespace something{
  enum myEnum{
    Val0 = 0,
    Val1 = 1,
    Val2 = 2,
    Val3 = 3,
  //...
  //Valn = n
  };
}
```

you can also use something like this as an alias for values

```
enum onlywhatiwant{
  Val1 = something::Val1,
  Val3 = something::Val3
  // etc
};
```